# PHP imagettftext() equivalent function in C++/Java/Python

Tags: java, php, c++, python, imagettftext

Is there any simple equivalent of PHP function imagettftext() in C++ / Java / Python libraries ?

http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagettftext.php

Answer (score 1):

in python you can use `PIL`:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont
font = ImageFont.truetype("/usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-bitstream-vera/Vera.ttf", 18)
img = Image.open("test.jpg")
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
draw.text((40, 40), "...sample text...", font=font, fill="red")
img.show()
```

in java you can simply draw on any `java.awt.Image` instance:

```
import javax.imageio.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class ImageTest {
   public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
      BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(new File("test.jpg"));
      Graphics2D g = img.createGraphics();
      Font f = Font.createFont(
            Font.TRUETYPE_FONT,
            new File("/usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-bitstream-vera/Vera.ttf")
      ).deriveFont(18f);
      g.setFont(f);
      g.setColor(Color.RED);
      g.drawString("test string", 40, 40);
      JFrame jf = new JFrame("test");
      jf.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(img)));
      jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      jf.setVisible(true);
      jf.pack();

   }
}
```

for c++ there are a lot of image libraries ([imagemagick-bindings](http://www.imagemagick.org/Magick++/), [CImg](http://cimg.sourceforge.net/), ...)